# Prepare json only keys matching in loop

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

I have json where it may have 1k records and i need to filter and prepare a json if keys matches with the list of keys provided.

Json:

```
{
  "updated_data":{
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following",
    "target": "name1",
    "liked": 21,
    "watched": 7,
    "commented": 0,
    "followed": false,
    "unfollowed": false,
    "scraped": false,
    "pm_sent": false
  },
   "updated_data":{
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following",
    "target": "name1",
    "liked": 21,
    "watched": 7,
    "commented": 0,
    "followed": false,
    "unfollowed": false,
    "scraped": false,
    "pm_sent": false
  },
   "updated_data":{
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following",
    "target": "name1",
    "liked": 21,
    "watched": 7,
    "commented": 0,
    "followed": false,
    "unfollowed": false,
    "scraped": false,
    "pm_sent": false
  },
   "updated_data":{
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following",
    "target": "name1",
    "liked": 21,
    "watched": 7,
    "commented": 0,
    "followed": false,
    "unfollowed": false,
    "scraped": false,
    "pm_sent": false
  },
   "updated_data":{
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following",
    "target": "name1",
    "liked": 21,
    "watched": 7,
    "commented": 0,
    "followed": false,
    "unfollowed": false,
    "scraped": false,
    "pm_sent": false
  },
   "updated_data":{
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following",
    "target": "name1",
    "liked": 21,
    "watched": 7,
    "commented": 0,
    "followed": false,
    "unfollowed": false,
    "scraped": false,
    "pm_sent": false
  }
}
```

But i need only

```
['session_id','following_status','job_name','last_interaction']
```

i need to iterate json and if matches the keys in the above list i need to get those key values and push to a new json file

Output may look like

```
[
  {
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following"
    
  },
  {
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following"
  },
  {
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following"
  },
  {
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following"
  },
  {
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following"
  },
  {
    "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
    "following_status": "followed",
    "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
    "job_name": "blogger-following"
  }
]
```

Am trying :

```
new_data = []
for jsonData in data:
    record_data = jsonData
    record_data_keys = record_data.keys()
    if 'target' in record_data_keys:
        del record_data['target']
    #so all not required one am deleting from json (here i just shown first and last for example)
    if 'pm_sent' in record_data_keys:
        del record_data['pm_sent']
    new_data.append(record_data)
```

Is there a better and fast way to make this more optimal way for getting desired output.

Please suggest

Comment: Instead of deleting data that is not needed and appending the rest, why not only append data you need? Seems a bit convoluted to me.

Comment: i have posted only sample data .. i have 8K key values and i need only 7k key values from json.. so am here

Comment: And why is that not mentioned in your question?

Comment: am new bee.. Sorry

Comment: Just try to be consise about what issue you're facing and what your limitations are. In your case, it would make sense to delete the minority of unnecessary keys.

Comment: next time i will keep in mind

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get only items you want:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter


with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

items = ["session_id", "following_status", "job_name", "last_interaction"]

i = itemgetter(*items)
out = [dict(zip(items, i(v))) for v in data]

now = datetime.now()
for d in out:
    d["updated_date"] = now
    d["updated_by"] = "dev"

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
        "following_status": "followed",
        "job_name": "blogger-following",
        "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
        "updated_date": datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 16, 15, 32, 3, 911459),
        "updated_by": "dev",
    },
    {
        "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
        "following_status": "followed",
        "job_name": "blogger-following",
        "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
        "updated_date": datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 16, 15, 32, 3, 911459),
        "updated_by": "dev",
    },

...
```

Comment: If i want to add a new key value from another list to same output.. can i do in this only?

Comment: i mean , which is not present in json... if i want to add a new key and value while matching with keys in list.. Can i do that?

Comment: @ditil You can add the new key as the second step. What should be the values of this new key?

Comment: 2 new key values {"updated_date": datetime.now, "updated_by":"dev"}

Comment: One small issue. my data is coming {"updated_data":{}} updated in question

Comment: my input json is coming in different format. Can you please check my input json. Updated in question

Comment: please help in the new input json structure

Comment: if am giving out = [dict(zip(items, i(v['updated_data']))) for v in data] not working, please help

Comment: even i tried this. out bot getting as expected  out = [dict(zip(items, v)) for v in enumerate(data[0]['updated_data'].items())]